# Создание асинхронного Wsasocket`а в Winscok

Tags: winsock

Подскажите пожалуйста, какую роль играет 4ый параметр в функции Wsasocket ---> структура WSAPROTOCOL_INFO?
То есть, я конечно прочитал на MSDN`е, что:

> которая определяет характеристики создаваемого сокета. Если этот
> параметр не равен NULL , сокет будет привязан к провайдеру, связанному
> с указанной структурой WSAPROTOCOL_INFO .

Правильно ли я понимаю, что данные этой структуры как бы расширяют опции создаваемого сокета, то есть первыми двумя параметрами Wsasocket - задаются более общие опции сокета, а WSAPROTOCOL_INFO - их более детализирует ?

Comment: По идее да, но зачем вам оно понадобилось?

Comment: user7860670, ну сделать http запрос на сайт. В идеале еще и как то потом приделать ssl и сделать уже https запрос.

Comment: Я спрашивал про 4й параметр. Он же опциональный.

Comment: user7860670, да я вот и хотел уточнить для чего его вообще можно использовать и кому он может понадобится.